# update 100ks of rows in MySQL with single query and without knowing key

Tags: php, mysql

One of my last questions came down to this topic and I didn't get an exact response:

I am selecting data from one table, running certain tasks on the data, then inserting the new data into a 2nd table.  If the new data matches an existing row in table 2, then I want to do an update.  The problem is that, there is no key to check for dupes.  If the new data row matches an existing row based on 2 fields, then its considered a dupe in which case it needs to update.

The closest thing I've seen to an answer is this:
http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/articles/sql/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

However, Im not sure if this is the right direction I should go in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL insert on duplicate key update multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230664/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-values)

Comment: "If the new data row matches an existing row based on 2 fields" - why not use these two fields as your PK?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a PK, a unique key on 2 fields is enough.

Comment: the problem is that neither one of these 2 fields need to be unique, but if no combination of these 2 fields conbined are found then the row is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your 2nd table to add a unique key that is the combination of the two columns, then use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Edit:

Just to be clear, indexes are not limited to a single column.  You can create an index that is a combination of columns:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE INDEX(column1, column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see - You have two tables and you want to create third table without any duplication. It is quite easy - first of all, duplicate one table. second of all, we will select the rows from the other table that doesn't have duplications with the first one.

```
INSERT INTO table3 (table3.col1, table3.col2 )
(SELECT table1.src, table1.col1, table1.col2
FROM table1 WHERE table1.col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table2));
```

the col1 is where you check Duplications. the query will be very slow.